# Making questions required under certain conditions

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to make a question required under a specific condition (so I can't just click the required box). I want questions to be required if the visit is in real time, and optional if the user is recording a past visit. Looking for advice for validation conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is currently impossible in CommCare. The best workaround I can suggest is making two questions:

- One that is required and displays only to real-time visitors
- One that is optional and displays only to past visits